# Finding straight line between 2 points in C

Tags: c, math, logic

Trying to make a game and I need entities to pathfind from their current location to another point in a straight line. I've currently got the following code:

```
void pathfind_test(path_data my_path[], int *path_to, double *x, double *y)
//path_data just has a column and a row (grid co-ordinates in the game)
//path_to is the array index to pathfind to
//x and y are the entities coordinates

{
  my_path += *path_to;
  int path_to_x = my_path->col * 60 - 30;
  int path_to_y = my_path->row * 60 - 30;
  //converts grid co-ordinates to X,Y co-ordinates
  double rise = path_to_y - *y;
  double run = path_to_x - *x;
  double grad = sqrt(rise * rise + run * run);

  if ((rise != 0) && (run != 0))
  {
    *y = *y + (rise / grad);
    *x = *x + (run / grad);
  }
  else
  {
    if (path_to_x > *x) {*x = *x + 1;}
    if (path_to_x < *x) {*x = *x - 1;}
    if (path_to_y > *y) {*y = *y + 1;}
    if (path_to_y < *y) {*y = *y - 1;}
  }

  if ((path_to_y == *y) && (path_to_x == *x)) {*path_to += 1;}
  if (*path_to == 40)
  {
    *x = 1200;
    *y = 150;
    *path_to = 0;
  }
}
```

but whenever the entity gets within a pixel distance it kind of shakes on the spot and never actually reaches the true X,Y co-ordinate.

Whilst travelling it also isnt a smooth travel, its kind of shaky.

I'm thinking that my variables aren't getting precise enough numbers to path that extra little bit at the end, so I thought this code would help but it makes the entity teleport which also supports my theory that the values aren't precise enough:

```
if ((rise / grad) + (run / grad) < 1)
{
  *x = path_to_x;
  *y = path_to_y;
}
else
{
  *y = *y + (rise / grad);
  *x = *x + (run / grad);
}
```

Dunno how to fix this logic and make it a smooth transition between x,y co-ords.

Comment: If you are trying to solve a problem in C, why is this question tagged with C++?

Comment: Floating point operation on computers are prone to rounding problems due to how floating point values are implemented on computers. These rounding problems compound and becomes larger and larger the more operations you perform on the numbers. So it's very likely that you get a very good approximation but can't actually get an exact value in the end. Using types with higher precision might help (e.g. `long double` instead of `double`) but the same flaw exists for all floating point operations.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It was a mistake. Edited to remove the wrong tag

Comment: You might like to research the [Bresenham line drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) - it is done with integers. You are not actually drawing a line but the principle might help.

Comment: In `path_to_y == *y` you are testing equality between double, since `path_to_y ` will be promoted to double. Floating point computations feature a finite precision and equality between double is rare... You could try to add a tolerance, something like `if(abs(path_to_y-*y)<1e-10+1e-10*abs(path_to_y))`...

Comment: @francis Your code fixed it thank you. Could you please explain what it's doing?

Comment: Note: Simplification `sqrt(rise * rise + run * run);` --> `hypot(rise, run);`  `if ((rise != 0) && (run != 0))` --> `if (grad)`

Comment: The problem is that `path_to_y == *y` is often wrong due to the finite precision of floating point computation. To prevent that, the equality test is replaced by a comparison: is the point close enough to the target ? `abs(path_to_y-*y)` represent the distance. "close enough" is left to be defined. It may be an absolute distance `1e-10` or a relative distance `1e-10*abs(path_to_y)`. Indeed, if `path_to_y` is 1e42 and  `*y` is 1.00000000001e42, the point can be defined as being "close enough". The way you define "close enough" is up to you !

Comment: @francis Why recommend `int abs(int)` instead of `double fabs(double)`?

Comment: @chux : sorry, my fault, fabs() would be better...

Comment: So I originally used @francis code and put `if((abs(path_to_y-*y)<1e-10+1e-10*abs(path_to_y)) && (abs(path_to_x-*x)<1e-10+1e-10*abs(path_to_x))) {*path_to += 1;}` and it worked fine but when I changed `abs` to `fabs` it didn't. Is there something else in my code I need to change for `fabs` to work @chux ?

Comment: You can try to tune the precision `1e-10`-> `1e-6`. I think `abs()` did the job because increments are of size 1. Hence, in average, it's hard to get closer to a target than about 0.5...